# What does scheduIndex means in pallet_vesting public functions merge_schedule

Tags: pallet, vesting

I am working on `pallet_vesting`. There is a public function of pallet_vesting with a signature similar to the following:

```rs
schedule1_index: u32,
schedule2_index: u32,
```

What do `schedule1_index` and `schedule2_index` here mean?

How do I get index of schedule for an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An account could have a lot of vestings.

e.g.

```rs
Vesting::get(Alice) = vec![
  vesting_for_a, // index 0
  vesting_for_b, //       1
  vesting_for_c, //       2
  vesting_for_d  //       3
];
```

You want to merge `vesting_a` and `vesting_d`. You need to provide the indexes to the call.

```rs
merge(0, 3);
```

---

> How do I get index of schedule for an account?

Just get the storage and enumerate it to get the indexes.

Check the example above.

---

Storage reference:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8d0b7564d5ba9ee0223a84f72ed15ac64c3be068/frame/vesting/src/lib.rs#L200